# Warning: fopen(write2File.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

Have been trying to fix this error for hours now.

Warning: fopen(write2File.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/2i/fwrite.php on line 3
can't open file.

I've searched for solutions everywhere including using "$ chmod 777" or "sudo chmod -R 777".

But i'm still very new to PHP and i've read that those 2 solutions come with security risks and i do not feel comfortable doing it since my macbook is still new + i'm still inexperience in PHP.

I'm looking for a safer solution. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about permissions and users in the Unix world.

The way to resolve this problem in a secure way will depend on how everything is configured.

On your own computer, if you are just making tests or learning, you could just set it as "666" and forget it. (That's: chmod 666 ...).

777 is wrong, because that will make the file executable, and you do not want that. 666 on the other hand will result in rw-rw-rw-, that means: readable and writeable by anyone, but not executable.

If you upload that to a server, then you will probably do it via FTP which will set permissions for you.

However, if you really want to understand what is going on and handle that securely, you should find out which user is your PHP running as. It may be www-data, or some other user. Then, this user will need to have permissions for your file. So you will probably change that file's owner and group via chown, so both you and PHP can access it, but other users can't.

Comment: hello, thank you for the help!! much appreciated

Comment: Happy to be helpful. I don't understand why did they close the question, since I find it perfecly clear, but, well, the important is that you got your answer.